# Псевдоним домена для гугл почты

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Есть консоль администратора для гугл корп почты,  по инструкции ( https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=ru ) добавил псевдоним  домена, проверифировал его ( скрин http://prntscr.com/dll5rx).
С момента  добавления прошло уже боллее 40 часов.
Но доставка email по адресам вида user@new_alias.com так и не заработала, хотя по документации должна  была.  Подскажите  что я  делаю не так.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать техподдержке компании Google.

Answer (score 1):

Вы настроили записи MX для домена?

У верифицированного домена появляется ссылка "Настроить записи MX для Google".

Необходимо пройти по этой ссылке и выполнить указанные инструкции. В частности перейти на сайт организации, где вы разместили доменное имя, отключить штатные почтовые MX и вместо них добавить следующие:

```
Адрес сервера MX    Приоритет

ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.         1
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.    5
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.    5
ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.     10
ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.     10
```

Тип создаваемых записей должен быть MX, разумеется.